# What is the best English translation for "Anreise" for a company website menu?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

On a company website one usually has a page which tells customers how to get to the company offices.

In German, the word for this menu tab is "Anreise" but both standard translations sound odd in English:

- Arrival
- Journey

What is a one-word menu title for such a menu item? The only one I can think of is:

- Location

What is the best English translation in this context for *Anreise*?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange

Comment: Just look up some English websites of larger companies and see what they use. (Usually they use something like "how to get here".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper translation is *Directions*. See https://dict.leo.org/german-english/directions